# Call method on various user controls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have created a number of custom user controls in my application. They are controls which validate their own content using a Validates() method.  When I click a button on the form, I would like to call this method on any control which has the method.  What is the best way to achieve this?

I'm able to identify and the controls and check if they have the method, but unsure how to call it at this point.  (All the controls begin with 'cc')

```
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Name.Length > 2 && c.Name.Substring(0, 2).Equals("cc"))
            {
                var type = c.GetType();
                if (type.GetMethod("Validates") != null)
                {
                    // Call method here
                }
            }
        }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or perhaps a better way I can do this.  I expect these controls will be on a lot of forms so i'd like to make a grouped validation as easy as possible from the parent form.

Thanks,

Comment: Are these custom controls that you have created?

Comment: Yes. Basically custom textboxes which use Regex to validate themselves depending on what's been chosen at design time.

Comment: Ok, see my answer about form validating events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try to use an Interface

```
public interface IValidateMyData
{
    bool Validate();
}

public class ValidationControl : Control, IValidateMyData
{
    // code here
    public bool Validate()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In your Form iterate over all controls like above but don't check on the name but determine if the control implements the IValidateMyData Interface:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if ( c is IValidateMyData )
    {
        var validationResult = (c as IValidateMyData).Validate();
    }
}
```

with this method your controls are not bound to have a specific name prefix.

furthermore you can move the iteration over all controls the validation to a baseclass which your form inherits from and just call the "ValidateAllControls()" Method in your form.

Comment: To save casting twice, do an `as` cast and check for null: `IValidate validateControl = c as IValidate; if(validateControl != null)`.

Comment: Perfect. I really should get into the habit of using interfaces!

Comment: @Simon yes you should, however in this instance just be aware of doing validation in a different way to the standard WinForms controls!

Comment: @TrevorPilley: thanks Trevor, I've taken it onboard. For now, this solution will suit my needs but for future i'll look into event based validation

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do it in WinForms is to use the [Form Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603.aspx) events.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an `interface` and every control having `Validate` method should implement that interface.

```
public interface IValidatable
{
    void Validates();
}
```

and check the interface in the loop.

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
  IValidatable validateControl = c as IValidatable;
  if(validateControl != null)
  {

       // do the validation.
       validateControl.Validates();
  }
```