# WPF Call Method On User Control With Binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I created a Task List control. I have an AddTask method on it. I'd like to call this method from the host Window.

I found a few posts here in SO and other sites that suggest using an interface, then looping over all the controls in the window to find the control, then getting a reference to it and using that to call the method. Here's an example:
[Call method on various user controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175208/call-method-on-various-user-controls)

But is it possible to call a method somehow with binding? Assume someone is using MVVM and the Window's VM wants to fire the control's AddTask method. is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Why does it have an AddTask method? Shouldn't it take a list of tasks as a binding?

Comment: Because AddTask will open a Task dialog, and if it's saved, adds it to the list. All of the functionality is encapsulated in the UC.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it (in a possible) the right way i'd tell you to write about **MVVM**.

Binding and methods work very well in MVVM using **Commands**

Here it is my solution

1. Create a ViewModel class
2. Create a nested class `MyCommandBehaviour` that implements `ICommand` (some people create the class in a different class)
3. In the view model create a property `MyCommandBehaviour MyCommand`
4. In the constructor of the view model instantiate that property
5. In The XAML bind the button `{Binding MyCommand}`
6. Set the `DataContext` of the window (or user control) to the view model

**Note**: I usually create the Command nested class with a constructor that accepts the 'parent' view model. Because the class is nested it can directly access the view model private members

```
        public class OkCommand : System.Windows.Input.ICommand
        {
            private MyViewModel _vm;
            public OkCommand(MyViewModel vm)            
            {
                this._vm = vm;
            }

            public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                return true;//I never use this and the event below
            }

#pragma warning disable 0067
            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
#pragma warning restore 0067

            public void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                //do your stuff. Note you can access the MyViewModel members here via _vm
            }
        }
```

Comment: [(or user control)] != [i'd tell you to write about MVVM] no viewmodel for usercontrols in mvvm and at all